# Adding other links on header than LinkedIn, Facebook, Youtube etc

Tags: customization, custom-header

As you can see on the header of my [website](http://www.stefanheymans.be) I have several link buttons to Youtube, Facebook etc...

I changed the code a bit to add Soundcloud URL, and that worked. I get the Soundcloud logo on top with the link. Unfortunately this didn't work for StackExchange. Is there any way I can create it myself? I have no idea where these images are.
This is the code from the Zero Gravity theme:

```
<?php if( get_theme_mod( 'zerogravity_youtube_url' ) !== '' ) { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_theme_mod( 'zerogravity_youtube_url', 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCgbFVVZZGxZt25qTaNnL7LA' )); ?>" title="YouTube" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if( get_theme_mod( 'zerogravity_stackexchange_url' ) !== '' ) { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_theme_mod( 'zerogravity_superuser_url', 'http://stackexchange.com/users/3651287/batchz4life' )); ?>" title="Stackexchange" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-stackexchange"></i></a>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if( get_theme_mod( 'zerogravity_pinterest_url' ) !== '' ) { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_theme_mod( 'zerogravity_pinterest_url', 'https://pinterest.com/stefanfare' )); ?>" title="Pinterest" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if( get_theme_mod( 'zerogravity_soundcloud_url' ) !== '' ) { ?>
            <a class="soundcloud" href="<?php echo esc_url(get_theme_mod( 'zerogravity_soundcloud_url', 'https://soundcloud.com/stefan-heymans-1/' )); ?>" title="Soundcloud" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-soundcloud"></i></a>          
        <?php } ?>
    </div><!-- .social-icon-wrapper --> 
</div><!-- .top-bar --->
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These icons are from Font Awesome: https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/

You can use for example Stack Exchange icon too with this code: `<i class="fa fa-stack-exchange"></i>`

If this code doesn't work, you should download the latest Font Awesome package or just link that in the header: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`